# Esri ArcGIS Portal selector window not filtering data view

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I have created a selector box in the header of a web app I am creating in ArcGIS Portal. It is an Ops Dashboard-type web app. I have all of the pie and serial charts responding to the map extent and the category selection (from the selector). But the data view is static. It will not filter for the categories I have selected. I know I should go to the Selector/Activity/select data layer as target and tell it to filter, but (here is the source of the problem) the data layer will not show up in this list unless the Selector is configured for Features (see image)[image]

But when I go to Actions, there is no capability to add a filter:[image]

But even if there was, I need grouped values in the configuration. Why are the right options not showing up and how do I fix this?